# Scala/Play/REPL: Configuration error (play.api.libs.Crypto)

Tags: java, scala, encryption, playframework, playframework-2.0

I don't understand, why am I getting this error in Scala Play REPL, but everything seems to be fine on Play project. This is after I run `play console`:

```
scala> import play.api.libs.Crypto
import play.api.libs.Crypto

scala> Crypto.encryptAES("password")
@6gd0e7jca: Configuration error
    at play.api.libs.Crypto$$anonfun$encryptAES$2.apply(Crypto.scala:156)
    at play.api.libs.Crypto$$anonfun$encryptAES$2.apply(Crypto.scala:156)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at play.api.libs.Crypto$.encryptAES(Crypto.scala:155)
    at .<init>(<console>:19)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:983)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:604)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:568)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.reallyInterpret$1(ILoop.scala:745)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:790)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:702)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine$1(ILoop.scala:566)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.innerLoop$1(ILoop.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:867)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:822)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:822)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:822)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.main(ILoop.scala:889)
    at xsbt.ConsoleInterface.run(ConsoleInterface.scala:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:102)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.console(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:77)
    at sbt.Console.sbt$Console$$console0$1(Console.scala:23)
    at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Console.scala:24)
    at sbt.TrapExit$.sbt$TrapExit$$executeMain$1(TrapExit.scala:33)
    at sbt.TrapExit$$anon$1.run(TrapExit.scala:42)
```

I want to use this for encrypting strings in the console. What exactly does this error mean?

Play Framework 2.2.1 / Scala 2.10.3 / Java 8 64bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a running Play application to encrypt anything with that method, because it needs to get the application secret to use to encrypt the data.

Two solutions:

1. Use the other version of `encryptKey`, and pass in your application secret, eg:

   ```
   Crypto.encryptAES("password", "yourapplicationsecret".substring(0, 16))
   ```
2. Instead of running `play console`, run `play test:console`, and then execute the following code in order to ensure that there is a running application:

   ```
   import play.api.test._
   Helpers.running(FakeApplication()) { Crypto.encryptAES("password") }
   ```